# What's the difference between the concepts "image" and backup?

Tags: backup

What's the difference between the concepts "image" and backup? Because I've read that they use both concepts more or less for the same. For example when they explain how macrium reflect works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the context.

An image copy could be your backup, or it could simply be your install/recovery media, needing an extra step to recover files from backup.

Your backup could be a complete image of the system or it could simply be the files you care about.

Answer (score 4):

Image is used as reference to `byte to byte copy` and it is one of ways to do backup.

Whenever backup as concept contain much more ways to create reliable copy.

Answer (score 1):

I think that backup is used when you want a copy the data which is only ment to you, but image of data represent each and every file(including the paratation details, details of each file like when it was created and all something like these) that too ment to computer.

Answer (score 0):

They are not interchangeable, but depending on the circumstance, *can be*. An image is where you copy, bit for bit, a filesystem, folder or singular file into one whole file - just like a zip archive, except compression may or may not be applied. Backups are often done with images, as you can image your entire system drive, and then if your SSD or HDD fails, you extract that same image onto your drive and it'll be an exact copy of that drive (at the time it was imaged, of course). It's MUCH more easier than re-copying your documents, settings and whatnot back to a new drive.

A backup is, in general, a copy (may not be identical) of your personal information, and is often referred to copies that can be easily restored back in case of drive failure. These are just copies, and can be an image, or just a drag-and-drop from your own computer to an external drive, for example.

You can use imaging for backing up, or for just preserving a drive's contents, should you wish to explore it later. For example, I image my own system drive monthly, and if I ever need to restore it if my SSD fails, I can restore that image onto a new SSD and it'd be fully identical (the firmware and serial number of the drive may differ but this has no impact on the system files restored onto it).

Similarly, you can back up using imaging, or by a handful of other means. The two are often used together but should be seen as exclusive of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Consider imaging as cloning: making a perfect copy.
You can image not only a file, but also a partition or a whole data carrier like an hard disk drive for instance.

Image is used to mean a `bit to bit` copy. (a bit is the most elementary data unit, taking "1" or "0" state.) Because the elementary data storage unit is the byte, a group of 8-bits, we can tell by extension `byte to byte` copy.

Unlike a backup, which is in its most basic form a file copy, and which depends on the file system (e.g. NTFS, FAT32, ext3, HFS+, ...) a clone is basically unaware of the file system, which traditionnally remains unmounted. So it is possible to duplicate all files from a partition being totally unaware of those files and considering the partition as a sequence of 0 and 1 that will be replicated `byte to byte`, `sector by sector` (group of bytes) or whichever the block size you want.

It is possible to do this from one data carrier (e.g. a HDD) to another one (e.g. another HDD) or to a regular file. In this second case, we tell this file is an image of the source (e.g. "CloneOfMyUSBKey.img" being an image file of the memory space of your USB key).

To illustrate the difference. If you clone your hard drive to another one, or if you restore your image to a hard drive, that hard drive will behave exactly like original drive. Typically you can launch the operating system, run softwares, a.s.o.
(There might be some exceptions when a software license depends on the hard drive serial number but that's another issue.)

On the contrary, if you only backup (=copy) your files (e.g. "Windows" and "Program Files" folders), you won't be able to fully restore the working state of your computer if your computer crashs, but will have to reinstall it.

Both images (clones) and backups are useful.

Images are to recommend when you want to restore everything (in case of a serious crash) or want to preserve the exact state of something (e.g. for data recovery or computer forensic investigations).

Backups (file copies) are to recommend when you want to save specific folder and files so that you can restore them quickly.